# How to remove diaeresis after hyphen

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

To quote Wikipedia:

> In Dutch, spellings such as coëfficiënt are necessary because the digraphs oe and ie normally represent the simple vowels [u] and [i], respectively. However, hyphenation is now preferred for compound words so that zeeëend (sea duck) is now spelled zee-eend.

Because the diaeresis is used to indicate that two letters should not be read as a digraph, it should be removed when this is indicated in an other way (a hyphen at a line break, for example). There are still cases where hyphenation removes the diaeresis: ‘financiën’ should be hyphenated as [‘fi-nan-ci-en’](http://woordenlijst.org/zoek/?q=financi%C3%ABn).

Unfortunately, when using

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{dutch}
```

the word is hyphenated as ‘financi-ën’ (when hyphenation happens at a line break). Is it possible to make XeLaTeX/Polyglossia remove the diaeresis when hyphenation happens?

The language-specific options in the Polyglossia manual do not offer a solution to this problem. The Babel manual mentions the `\@trema` macro, and indeed, when using pdfLaTeX and Babel, `financi"en` is hyphenated correctly (removing the diaeresis) at line breaks. I did find [this ugly hack](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2011-January/019851.html), but I am convinced there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If *all* “ë” just mean this, then a possible workaround is to redefine the meaning of `ë` to be `"e`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
\newunicodechar{ë}{\@trema e}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

financiën coëfficiënt zeeëend    

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}financiën coëfficiënt zeeëend}

\end{document}
```

The `\parbox{0pt}{...}` is a trick for telling TeX to hyphenate as much as possible.

[image]

With XeLaTeX you *can* use `babel` in the same fashion, just remove the calls to `fontenc` and `inputenc`.

If you want to use `polyglossia`, then here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{dutch}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\allowhyphens}{%
  \ifvmode\else\nobreak\hskip\z@skip\fi
}
\def\@trema#1{\allowhyphens\discretionary{-}{#1}{\"{#1}}\allowhyphens}

\newunicodechar{ë}{\@trema e}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

financiën coëfficiënt zeeëend

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}financiën coëfficiënt zeeëend}

\end{document}
```